# rotating a point using a previously rotated one

Tags: group-theory, transformation, rotations

I want to rotate a shape in an n dimensional space (n>3) around (about) the origin.
knowing the outcome of rotation on a point like A, which is A', how can I find the rotation outcome on a point like B. i.e. we know that A is transformed to A', can we find the point to which B is transformed?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are in the same orbit, then yes: use conjugation. That is, if there exists some $g\in G$ with $A^g=B$ (the action of $g$ maps $A$ to $B$) then $B^h=A^{gh}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598750/finding-the-rotation-matrix-in-n-dimensions.