# Finding a unitary matrix from generic matrix multiplication and renormalizing

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, unitary-matrices

Lets say we have a known unit vector, $v$.  Consider multiplying this vector by a known square matrix $M$ that keeps the vector in the space, but changes the direction and length of $v$ in general, $v \rightarrow v' = Mv$.  If we renormalize this vector to have unit length by dividing by $\sqrt{v' v'^{*}}$, we have moved between two vectors with length-one that point in different directions, which is a rotation.  Is there a way to find a unitary matrix that accomplishes this same rotation given $M$ and $v$?

This question seems similar and useful: [Finding the rotation matrix in n-dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/598750/22872) but the givens are the two vectors.  Here we only have $M$ and $v$ to use.

Thanks!

Comment: The map $v \mapsto \frac{\|v\|}{\|Mv\|}Mv$ is not generally a linear map and in particular is not necessarily a rotation

Comment: @Omnomnomnom but isn't there a rotation which accomplishes the same result?

Comment: Yes, there exists a rotation $R$ for which $Rv$ is the normalized vector.  It is incorrect to say, however, that "we have moved between two vectors with length-one that point in different directions, which is a rotation".

Comment: With that being said, if you want such a rotation then you could use the post you linked with $v$ and the normalized $v'$ as your two vectors.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, thank you for clarifying. No, I would like to extract the rotation part of $M$ directly, if possible.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom said another way, I would like to find a form for $M$ like $s U$ where $U$ is a rotation and $s$ a rescaling.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is a [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) of the form $M = PU$.  If this is what you're looking for, then you could take $U = M(M^*M)^{-1/2} = (MM^*)^{-1/2}M$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ah, I meant $s$ as a multiple of the identity.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense since most matrices $M$ are not a multiple of a rotation matrix (or unitary matrix) $U$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom they must be right? Or $s$ is zero. Since every vector can be normalized, and two vectors of the same length can be rotated into each other. Right?

Comment: If you choose a particular $v$, then there exists a scaling $s$ and unitary $U$ such that $Mv = sUv$.  This does not imply that $M = sU$; saying that $M = s U$ amounts to saying that there is a single rotation for which $Mx = sUx$ holds for **every** vector $x$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, but this is what I asked in the question.  Given $M$ and $v$, you can accomplish the same thing with a $s$ and a $U$.  I am wondering is there a way to find a $U$.

Comment: Ultimately, a formula for such a $U$ must depend on both $M$ and $v$.  One such formula comes from applying the ideas from the linked post to $v$ and the normalized $Mv$.