# angles of rotation in n-dimensions

Tags: vectors, rotations

What I want to do is to find  $n(n-1)/2$  angles of rotation given two n-D vectors $F_1$ and $F_2$ in Matlab. I suppose that for that I should know general form of transformation matrix $T$ such that $F_2 = T*F_1$. I can construct it for 3-D, 4-D, 5-D and so on manually, but have problems with generalisation for code implementation. Is there any general form of n-D transformation matrix? Or is there another way to find $n(n-1)/2$  angles of rotation?

Comment: Even in 3D the answer is not unique.

Comment: If you mean that even in 3D we have, for example, Euler angles and 
Tait–Bryan angles, I say that I want one (any) set of angles to describe rotation.

Comment: No, I mean that a rotation transferring _one_ given vector into another is not unique, no matter how you describe it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2161406) a super easy way to find a rotation matrix $R$ that rotates $u$ to align with $v$ in $N$ dimensions. $R$ is unique in the sense that it does not rotate vectors outside the subspace of $u$ and $v$.