# Calculating the rotation angles between two vectors.

Tags: matrices, vectors, rotations

I have the two vectors $ V1 = \begin{pmatrix}
0.577 \\
0.577 \\
0.577
\end{pmatrix} $ and $ V2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix} $

I need to find the rotation angles when rotating from V1 to V2 using Euler Angles - I must use the rotation matrix here:

R= $\begin{bmatrix} 
cos(\alpha)cos(\beta) & cos(\alpha)sin(\beta)sin(\gamma)-sin(\alpha)cos(\gamma) & cos(\alpha)sin(\beta)cos(\gamma)+sin(\alpha)sin(\gamma) \\
sin(\alpha)cos(\beta) & sin(\alpha)sin(\beta)sin(\gamma)+cos(\alpha)cos(\gamma) & sin(\alpha)sin(\beta)cos(\gamma)-cos(\alpha)sin(\gamma) \\
-sin(\beta) & cos(\beta)sin(\gamma) & cos(\beta)cos(\gamma)
\end{bmatrix}$

I know how to find the angles given R eg. $   \alpha = Atan2(R_{23},R_{33}) $

So what i am essentially missing is solving the equation Ax=b, where i have x and b.

I know this will yield multiple solutions, i just need any.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501943/n-dimensional-rotation-along-a-2d-arbitrary-plane/502438#502438

Answer (score 2):

Like you mentioned, there can be many solutions. So one way is to find an axis and get the rotation angle around that. Suppose $V_1$ is not parallel to $V_2$. Then $V_1+V_2$ is along the bisector of the angle between them. Use this as rotation axis. The rotation of $V_1$ around this axis will describe a cone. When you rotate $180^\circ$ you get a vector along $V_2$. Now you can use the [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) to get the rotation matrix. Similarly, you can get an axis perpendicular to $V_1$ and $V_2$ by using the cross product. The angle of rotation is given by the scalar (dot) product of the vectors.

In case $V_1$ and $V_2$ are parallel, you can choose any vector in the perpendicular plane and rotate $180^\circ$.

Comment: I used your idea to rotate between the two vectors, and with the help from [link](http://euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/angleToEuler/index.htm) i converted the axis angle to the euler angles i need.

Comment: I forgot to add the following:
Now, I want to expand on this solution so that V2 is a plane (normal vector) with the possibility to rotate other points onto that plane.
But using only the normal vector will not give me a unique result, where all 3 axis are where i want them. Is it possible to rotate only once with the formula you gave me and end up with all 3 axis lined up in a way i define?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you need more information. You want to rotate $v_1$ to $u_1$ (the normal) and $v_2$ to $u_2$ (a vector in the plane). You can get a third vector, also in the plane, $v_3$ and $u_3$ by using the cross product. Make a matrix $V$ with columns made out of $v_i$ and $U$ out of $u_i$. Then your rotation matrix transforms $V$ to $U$ by this formula: $RV=U$ or $R=UV^{-1}$.

Comment: I used the formula to get R. Choosing a vector in one system and doing R*V1 gives me the vector in the other system - Thanks!. However, extracting the axis&angle from R, and then rotating the same V1 with that axis&angle, does not produce the same result. Is it only possible to extract axis and angle from R, if it satisfies [link] 
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle)
How would I proceed to get the axis&angle from R, or the Euler Angles?
Or if R needs to satisfy above, how would I produce R (given V&U) in a way where i can extract the angle.