# need orthogonal basis for R3. i'm given one of them. how do i find the rest?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need orthogonal basis for R3. I am given v1 = (1,1,1), so I need so I need other two vectors in this basis but how do i find the other two?

at first i thought i would use gram schmidt but that doesn't seem plausible with just one vector.

Comment: Select two other vectors, so that the three are independent. Then G-S them.

Comment: You can start by finding two linearly indepedent vectors orthogonal to $v_1$ by solving a system. Then you'll have a basis of $\mathbb R^3$ and you can apply G-S. Or you can just 'guess' that with $v_2=(0,1,0)$ and $v_3=(0,0,1)$, the set $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is linearly independent and you can apply G-S.

Comment: Gram-Schmidt really is the way you'd want to go about this (because it works in any dimension), but since we are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ there is also a funny and simple alternative: take any non-zero vector orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$ (this can be found very easily) and then simply take the cross product of the two vectors. Pairwise orthogonality gives you, that the resulting set is linearly independent.

Answer (score 4):

Pick any vector $\mathbf u$ that is not a multiple of $\mathbf v_1$.
Set $\mathbf v_2 = \mathbf v_1 \times \mathbf u$.
Set $\mathbf v_3 = \mathbf v_1 \times \mathbf v_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Take for example:

$(1,-1,0)$

and

$(1,1,-2)$

Comment: Maybe you should some more details, so the OP can better understand your solution

Comment: It might be useful to explain how you got those vectors :)  For the OPs benefit: for the first vector, we can find a vector in the plane orthogonal to (a,b,c) by selecting (b,-a,0) (take their dot product to see this), so we get (1,-1,0).  For the third vector, take the cross-product of the two you now have; that gives you a vector orthogonal to the first two (i.e. (1,1,-2) here).

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" way is to find two more vectors then use Gram-Schmidt, as suggested by others.  For a short cut using trial and (not much) error, take $(1,-1,0)$ which is orthogonal to your first vector.  Then  $(1,1,a)$.  This is orthogonal to the second vector, and also to the first if you choose $a$ suitably.  I expect this is how Yiorgos obtained his answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just pick two more vectors arbitrarily and apply Gram-Schmidt. Gram-Schmidt preserves the direction of the first input vector, so you'll get a normalized copy of $(1, 1, 1)$.

Comment: Not arbitrarily. G-S requires the input to be a linearly independent set.