# Isometry of $S^2$ taking a point to $N=(1,0,0)$

Tags: geometry

While reading a related proof, the author of my geometry textbook states that there exists an isometry of the $2-Sphere$ or $S^2$ that can take any arbitrary point to the north pole.

I know that there are three types of isometries of $S^2$ namely a reflection in a line (about two antipodal points), a reflection in a great circle, and a spin reflection, but I'm unsure which of these (or what combination thereof) could result in the desired isometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure any kind of isometry could be made to work.

Given any point $P \neq N$, there's a great circle $C$ connecting $N$ and $P$ (it's unique, if $N$ and $P$ aren't antipodal). The points divide $C$ into two arcs, and the midpoints of these two arcs are antipodal. A half-turn about the line connecting these antipodal points would interchange $N$ and $P$ (there's also a rotation "along" $C$ that sends $P$ to $N$).

Alternatively, there's a great circle $C'$ perpendicular to $C$ and containing the two antipodal points above. A reflection through $C'$ also interchanges $N$ and $P$.

---

Since points of the $2$-sphere correspond to directions in $\Bbb R^3$, if you believe there are isometries of $\Bbb R^3$ that can send any $1$-dimensional subspace to the $z$-axis, this is (essentially) equivalent to what the author of the text is claiming.

Comment: Great answer. I'm not sure what you mean by "directions" in $\Bbb R^3$ however.

Comment: I didn't mean it in a technical sense; something like, if you're standing at the origin in $\Bbb R^3$, the directions are all the lines of sight.

Answer (score 2):

Any rotation about a diameter of the sphere will provide an isometry. For the arbitrary point in the question, there is a diameter that is perpendicular to each of the radii that join the centre to the arbitrary point and to the point $(1,0,0)$.

In general, if $\theta$ is the angle between these two radii, then rotatating about the diameter described above by $\theta$ will take the point to $(1,0,0)$ (taking care to get the sense of rotation right).

If an explicit calculation of the rotation matrix is needed, then the method described in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d) for rotating one vector onto another can be used.