# I have a face in 3D space that I would like to move and place (calculate rotation between vectors)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

Say I have a plane in 3-dimensional space:

[image: An arbitrary plane in 3D space]

I have a normal for the face in the form `<x,y,z>`

I have a rotate function, `rotate(x,y,z)`, which will rotate the plane by an amount in radians on each axis. I want to use this function to apply a rotation that will align the normal with another normal. For simplicity's sake, take an axis vector. Aligning it to the z-axis vector, `<0,0,1>`, would produce the following result on a Cartesian plane:

[image: Plane in 2D space]

Given two 3D vector directions, `v1` and `v2`, how can I derive a set of rotations on each axis to align `v1` to `v2`? I recognize that there are multiple 'ways around' to any given direction in 3D space, but in my case, only the solution is critical.

Similar to [Calculate Rotation Matrix to align Vector A to Vector B in 3d?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d), only I am not using a rotation *matrix*.

Comment: Do note that I realize the rotated result will not necessarily be aligned nicely like my example. Because of my specific application, performing a second rotation is required anyway.

Comment: Are you basically asking how to find the angle between two normals?

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_1 = \big(v_{x,1}, \,v_{y,1}, \, v_{z,1}\big)$ and $v_2 = \big(v_{x,2}, \,v_{y,2}, \, v_{z,2}\big)$. Let $R_z(\theta)$ be the rotation to an angle $\theta$ around axis $z$ counter-clockwise looking from the positive orientation of the $z$ axis. Let $R_y(\psi)$ be the rotation to an angle $\psi$ around axis $y$ counter-clockwise looking from the positive orientation of the $y$ axis. Then the composition of rotations:
$$R_{y,z}(v_1) = R_y\left( \, -\,\text{arccot} \left(\frac{v_{z,1}}{\sqrt{v_{x,1}^2 + v_{y,1}^2}}\right)\,\right)\, R_z\left( \,- \,\text{arccot}\left( \frac{v_{x,1}}{v_{y,1}} \right) \,\right)$$ rotates and aligns the vector $v_1$ with the coordinate unit vector $e_z = (0, 0, 1)$. If you want to go from $v_1$ to the vector aligned with $v_2$, simply set up the inverse rotation from $e_z$ to $v_2$: 
$$R_{y,z}(v_2)^{-1} = R_z\left( \,\text{arccot}\left( \frac{v_{x,2}}{v_{y,2}} \right) \,\right)\,R_y\left( \,\text{arccot} \left(\frac{v_{z,2}}{\sqrt{v_{x,2}^2 + v_{y,2}^2}}\right)\,\right)\, $$

and then the composition $$R_{y,z}(v_2)^{-1} R_{y,z}(v_1) $$ rotates $v_1$ to $v_2$. Have in mind that, depending on which quadrants the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ point into, you may or may not need to adjust how you define the function $y=\text{arccot}(x)$. Also, if you want to experiment with alternatives, you could check out the [conversion formulas from Cartesian to spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). It is related to your question.