# calculate a force vector in different frame

Tags: vectors, rotations

I have to calculate a force vector in a different frame. There are 3 distinct frame Local Sensor and Body frame the all of body and sensor frame are expressed on local frame by these vectors:

$S_{x}^{L} \begin{bmatrix} 1.3343\\ -0.7704\\ -0.7185 \end{bmatrix}$
$S_{y}^{L} \begin{bmatrix} 0.7925\\ 1.4979\\ -0.1343 \end{bmatrix}$
$S_{z}^{L} \begin{bmatrix} 0.6939\\ -0.2295\\ 1.539 \end{bmatrix}$
$B_{x}^{L} \begin{bmatrix} 1.4793\\ -1.4793\\ 0.1830 \end{bmatrix}$
$B_{y}^{L} \begin{bmatrix} 1.4399\\ 1.4848\\ 0.3633 \end{bmatrix}$

$B_{z}^{L} \begin{bmatrix} -0.3853\\ -0.1304\\ 2.0602 \end{bmatrix}$
$f_{s} \begin{bmatrix} -0.1\\ 0.05\\ -9.79 \end{bmatrix}$

i tried to figure out the different algorithm that are described in this article [Calculate Rotation Matrix to align Vector A to Vector B in 3d?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d)

Edit :
i used this script to calculate the rotation matrix from the $B_{x}^{L} $ to  $ S_{x}^{L} $

```
close all
clear
clc
v1=[1.3343 -0.7704 -0.7185]';
v2=[1.4793 -1.4793 0.1830]';
dcm= fcn_RotationFromTwoVectors(v1, v2)
c=dcm*v1
function R=fcn_RotationFromTwoVectors(v1, v2)
% R*v1=v2
% v1 and v2 should be column vectors and 3x1

% 1. rotation vector
w=cross(v1,v2);
w=w/norm(w);
w_hat=fcn_GetSkew(w);
% 2. rotation angle
cos_tht=v1'*v2/norm(v1)/norm(v2);
tht=acos(cos_tht);
% 3. rotation matrix, using Rodrigues' formula
R=eye(size(v1,1))+w_hat*sin(tht)+w_hat^2*(1-cos(tht));
end
function x_skew=fcn_GetSkew(x)
x_skew=[0 -x(3) x(2);
x(3) 0 -x(1);
-x(2) x(1) 0];
end
```

t tried to calculate if the resultant vector of rotated $ S_{x}^{L} $ but that didn't match the value of $ B_{x}^{L} $ .
in my approach i won't to calculate in first step the different DCM matrix to rotate over different frame L S B to be able to calculate the force vector in this frame

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. Instead, use MathJax to format your math expressions. To learn how, see [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation) for a basic summary, and [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) for a thorough documentation.

Comment: It might also help potential answerers to type up what you actually got when you attempted the problem, even if the result is not what you expected, because it will provide more information to help people address your question specifically. In general, it is a good idea to [add more context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960), for example by summarizing your own attempt.