# Calculate Rotation matrix to align two 3D vectors

Tags: rotations

I found a solution to find the rotation matrix to align two 3D vectors :

[Calculate Rotation Matrix to align Vector A to Vector B in 3d?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d)

In the given solution, the formula is very close to the one given for Rodrigues's rotation matrix formula considering the two initial vectors give us the angle (with the dot product) and the rotation axis (with the cross-product) :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula

Yet, when I apply numerically the two formulas, I find that the first solution gives more accurate results than Rodrigues's one.

Why is there such a numerical difference between the two formulas? What is the difference between the two?

Does the first solution have a name? I couldn't find any additional information, but I think it is because I do not have the correct keywords.