# Finding rotation matrix from two 3D vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, 3d, rotations, python

I'm trying to find the rotation matrix that maps one 3d vector to another with the same magnitude by rotating it around the origin. I'm doing it in python, but people on stack overflow don't seem to help. To start I have two methods: one to calculate an R matrix from two vectors and another to convert it to angles.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Rotation():
    
    # convert R matrix to angles
    def rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R):
        sy = math.sqrt(R[0,0] * R[0,0] +  R[1,0] * R[1,0])

        singular = sy < 1e-6

        if  not singular :
            x = math.atan2(R[2,1] , R[2,2])
            y = math.atan2(-R[2,0], sy)
            z = math.atan2(R[1,0], R[0,0])
        else :
            x = math.atan2(-R[1,2], R[1,1])
            y = math.atan2(-R[2,0], sy)
            z = 0
        return np.array([math.degrees(x), math.degrees(y), math.degrees(z)])

    # get R matrix from two vectors
    def get_rot_matrix(A, B):
        assert A.shape == B.shape
        v = np.cross(A, B)
        s = np.linalg.norm(v)
        c = np.dot(A, B)
        vx = np.array([[0, -v[2], v[1]], [v[2], 0, -v[0]], [-v[1], v[0], 0]]) 
        r = np.eye(3) + vx + (np.dot(vx, vx) * (1-c)/(s**2))
        return r
```

I think the problem is with the calculation of the rotation matrix but I'm not sure. I based the `get_rot_matrix()` method off of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/476311/899558). I ran some tests and heres what I found:

For simple rotation (rotation about 1 axis) the angle is correct, but when I try to apply the R matrix to the original starting point I don't get the target ending point.

```
# --------------- SIMPLE ROTATION ---------------------
print("SIMPLE ROTATION")

# create chart
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# add simple 90 degrees rotation to chart
ax.plot([0,0], [0,0],[-5,5]) # axis of rotation
ax.scatter(4,0,0) # start
ax.scatter(0,4,0) # end

# find and print calculated rotation angle
start = np.array([4,0,0])
end = np.array([0,4,0])
R = Rotation.get_rot_matrix(start, end)
print("Angles: \t" + str(Rotation.rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R)))

# apply rotation matrix to start point
end_attempt = np.dot(R, start)
print("End attempt: \t" + end_attempt.__str__())

# open chart
plt.title("Simple Rotation")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.legend(["axis of Rotation", "start", "end"])
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
SIMPLE ROTATION
Angles:         [ 0. -0. 90.]
End attempt:    [ 0. 64.  0.]
```

As you can see the end attempt should be `[0, 4, 0]` not `[0, 64, 0]`. Heres the graph of the rotation I'm doing:
[simple_rot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR8HC.jpg)

For complex rotation (rotation about multiple axis') I know that the end attempt is not correct, but I am not sure if the angles are correct. I don't really know how to check if they are!

```
# --------------- COMPLEX ROTATION ---------------------
print("\nCOMPLEX ROTATION")

# create chart
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# add complex rotation to chart
ax.scatter(0,0,0) # origin
ax.scatter(4,3,2) # start

# pythag theroem to find end point on y axis
length = math.sqrt(sum(a**2 for a in (1,4,2)))
ax.scatter(0,length,0) # end

# find and print calculated rotation angle
start = np.array([4,3,2])
end = np.array([0,length,0])
R = Rotation.get_rot_matrix(start, end)
print("Angles: \t" + str(Rotation.rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R)))

# apply rotation matrix to start point
end_attempt = np.dot(R, start)
print("End attempt: \t" + end_attempt.__str__())

# open chart
plt.title("Complex Rotation")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.legend(["origin", "start", "end"])
plt.show()
```

Output

```
COMPLEX ROTATION
Angles:         [-68.82925422 -13.3540114   58.57878746]
End attempt:    [5.32907052e-15 1.32894695e+02 2.66453526e-15]
```

Heres the graph: [complex_rot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSZIv.jpg)

Comment: There are infinitely many such rotations. Do you have a particular one in mind?

Comment: @CyclotomicField No I dont. I believe the answer I linked to was the most efficient way of doing it compared to all of the other answers. And by efficient I mean the least amount of rotation.

Comment: There are infinitely many that use exactly one rotation. For example you can rotate around an axis perpendicular to the plane or around the midpoint between the two vectors. The midpoint example generalizes readily a great circle of rotations that will work.

Comment: The second paragraph in the following  Wikipedia entry for quaternions might help: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rotate vector $\vec{a} = (a_x, a_y, a_z)$ to vector $\vec{b} = (b_x, b_y, b_z)$ when $\lVert\vec{a}\rVert = \lVert \vec{b} \rVert$, we need to rotate $\vec{a}$ around unit axis vector $\hat{n}$ by angle $\theta$, such that
$$\begin{aligned}
\hat{a} &= \frac{\vec{a}}{\left\lVert\vec{a}\right\rVert} = \frac{\vec{a}}{\sqrt{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{a}}} \\
\hat{b} &= \frac{\vec{b}}{\left\lVert\vec{a}\right\rVert} = \frac{\vec{b}}{\sqrt{\vec{b} \cdot \vec{b}}} \\
\hat{n} &= \frac{\vec{n}}{\left\lVert\vec{n}\right\rVert} = \frac{\vec{n}}{\sqrt{\vec{n} \cdot \vec{n}}} \\
\vec{n} &= \vec{a} \times \vec{b} \\
\sin \theta &= \left\lVert \hat{a} \times \hat{b} \right\rVert \quad \text{(not needed in this case)} \\
\cos \theta &= \hat{a} \cdot \hat{b} \\
\end{aligned}$$

Python implementation:

```
from math import sqrt, cos, sin, acos

def unit_axis_angle(a, b):
    an = sqrt(a[0]*a[0] + a[1]*a[1] + a[2]*a[2])
    bn = sqrt(b[0]*b[0] + b[1]*b[1] + b[2]*b[2])
    ax, ay, az = a[0]/an, a[1]/an, a[2]/an
    bx, by, bz = b[0]/bn, b[1]/bn, b[2]/bn
    nx, ny, nz = ay*bz-az*by, az*bx-ax*bz, ax*by-ay*bx
    nn = sqrt(nx*nx + ny*ny + nz*nz)
    return (nx/nn, ny/nn, nz/nn), acos(ax*bx + ay*by + az*bz)
```

The returned axis and angle we can convert to a rotation matrix trivially.  If our arrays describe column vectors, and we multiply matrices and vectors with matrix on the left,
$$\mathbf{R} \vec{a} = \vec{c} \quad \iff \quad \begin{bmatrix}
R_{11} & R_{12} & R_{13} \
R_{21} & R_{22} & R_{23} \
R_{31} & R_{32} & R_{33} \
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_x \ a_y \ a_z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} c_x \ c_y \ c_z \end{bmatrix}$$
then

```
def rotation_matrix(axis, angle):
    ax, ay, az = axis[0], axis[1], axis[2]
    s = sin(angle)
    c = cos(angle)
    u = 1 - c
    return ( ( ax*ax*u + c,    ax*ay*u - az*s, ax*az*u + ay*s ),
             ( ay*ax*u + az*s, ay*ay*u + c,    ay*az*u - ax*s ),
             ( az*ax*u - ay*s, az*ay*u + ax*s, az*az*u + c    ) )

def multiply(matrix, vector):
    return ( matrix[0][0]*vector[0] + matrix[0][1]*vector[1] + matrix[0][2]*vector[2],
             matrix[1][0]*vector[0] + matrix[1][1]*vector[1] + matrix[1][2]*vector[2],
             matrix[2][0]*vector[0] + matrix[2][1]*vector[1] + matrix[2][2]*vector[2] )
```

Nothing beats an unit test.  So, let's generate a couple of random vectors, scale the second to the same length as the first, and verify that when applied to the first vector, it yields the second vector, within rounding error:

```
from random import Random
rng = Random()

a = (rng.uniform(-5,5), rng.uniform(-5,5), rng.uniform(-5,5))
b = (rng.uniform(-5,5), rng.uniform(-5,5), rng.uniform(-5,5))

s = sqrt((a[0]*a[0] + a[1]*a[1] + a[2]*a[2]) / (b[0]*b[0] + b[1]*b[1] + b[2]*b[2]))
b = (b[0]*s, b[1]*s, b[2]*s)

axis, angle = unit_axis_angle(a, b)
c = multiply(rotation_matrix(axis, angle), a)
print("a = (%9.6f, %9.6f, %9.6f)" % a)
print("b = (%9.6f, %9.6f, %9.6f)" % b)
print("c = (%9.6f, %9.6f, %9.6f)" % c)
```

Note that the above functions returns tuples, which are immutable.  If you want mutable results, just return lists (`(..)` $\to$ `[..]`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating a vector $A$ to a vector $B$ having the same magnitude as $A$, is straight forward and not ambiguous at all.

The rotation you request is about an axis passing through the origin.

The unit vector along the axis lies in the plane passing through the origin, and having a normal vector equal to the vector $\vec{AB}$.  There is an infinite number of such vectors. However the axis that minimizes the angle of rotation is the one that is along the cross product between $A$ and $B$.  Hence, we'll select our axis of rotation to be the unit vector $a$

$ a = \dfrac{ A \times B }{\| A \times B \| }$

The angle of rotation $\theta$ is given by

$ \theta = \sin^{-1} \left( \dfrac{ \| A \times B \| }{ \| A \|^2 } \right) $

Now all you have to do is use the well-known **Rodrigues' rotation matrix formula** to compute your rotation matrix $R$

$R = {a a}^T + (I - {a a}^T ) \cos(\theta) + S_a \sin(\theta) $

where

$ S_a = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && - a_z && a_y \\ a_z && 0 && -a_x \\ -a_y && a_x && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

That's it!!

Now to verify the above, suppose you have vector $A = (1, -4, 8) $ and $B = (4, -8, 1) $, then you can carry out the above computations to end up with the matrix $R$, and then pre-multiply $A$ with the matrix $R$, and you should have

$ B = R A $

Comment: what is the aa notation. Regular multiplication? dot product?

Comment: $a$ is considered a column vector, while $a^T$ is a row vector, then ${a a}^T$ is their matrix matrix product, it has 3 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing it into python (and therefore accepting it) because of a minor inaccuracy. Feel free to check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73045412/how-to-solve-inaccuracy-in-3d-rotation-matrix

Comment: Also shouldnt the final equation be R dot A?

Comment: I noticed in the line for computing $R$ that you do not use the dot function for multiplying $a$ and $a^T$.  I don't know python, but I know the method described in my solution above is correct.  So please check your code, I don't any issues with my implementation.

Comment: I made some modifications to your code and got it to work.

The modified code is found [here](https://www.online-python.com/4QbB3fnDK1)