# Calculate rotation matrix to rotate a matrix A (3d points x,y,z) to be orthogonal by 3D normal vector N

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, 3d, orthogonal-matrices

I have a matrix A, which is the coordinates of a circle in 3D space. I want to rotate the circle in a way that its normal vector (orthogonal to the circle) be aligned with vector N:(x_n,y_n,z_n). I'd appreciate it if you help me with the script in Matlab.

PS: I only have matrix A [49 x 3] and vector N [1 x 3], which is the desired normal vector.

Comment: Do you know  in advance the normal vector of the circle whose points you start with?

Comment: @BenGrossmann: What does it mean for a circle to have a normal vector?  Normal to the plane the circle lies in?

Comment: @hardmath yes${}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suppose for now that you already have the normal vector of the circle. In fact, I suspect that this normal vector is $(0,0,1)$, but I won't assume this for now. Let $a$ denote the starting normal vector, and let $b = N$ denote the target normal vector.

We could calculate a suitable rotation matrix using the procedure [outlined here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d). Take $v = a \times b$, $s = \|v\|$, and $s = a \cdot b$. As the linked answer states, we can use the rotation matrix
$$
R = I + [v]_\times + \frac{1-c}{s^2}[v]_\times^2, \quad [v]_\times = \pmatrix{
\,\,0 & \!-v_3 & \,\,\,v_2\\
\,\,\,v_3 & 0 & \!-v_1\\
\!-v_2 & \,\,v_1 &\,\,0}.
$$
Here's a script to produce this matrix for example vectors `a,b`.

```
a = [1,2,3];
b = [-1,1,0];
v = cross(a,b);
s = norm(v)^2;
c = a*b';
c_mat = [[0,-v(3),v(2)];
          [v(3),0,-v(1)];
          [-v(2),v(1),0]];
R = eye(3) + c_mat + ((1-c)/s^2)*c_mat^2;
```

You can confirm that computing `R*a'` (or equivalently, `a*R'`) yields a result that is parallel to `b`.

From there you could multiply each row by `R` using a for loop, but a nicer approach is to simply get the rotated points with `B = A*R'`.

If we want to rotate the points in `A` about the center of the circle, we could do the following.

```
center = mean(A);
B = (A - center)*R' + center;
```

---

If for some reason you need to find the starting normal vector of the circle, then one quick way to get an answer is with `a = null(A - A(1,:))'`.

Similarly, instead of using the cross-product to get `v`, you could use `v = null([a;b])'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure why it transforms my rotated points. However, the normal vector of the rotated points is parallel to the desired normal vector ( it shows it's perfectly aligned with the desired normal vector). Is there any way I can keep my points in the initial position and rotate it in its position?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "rotate it in its position"? Do you mean that you want to rotate the circle about its center?

Comment: Yes Exactly. The current code transforms the circle to another position.

Comment: @ash See my latest edit

Comment: Great, it works!